# Jest test case gives Unexpected token in dynamic import() error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, jestjs, create-react-app

I have generated a react app using `create-react-app` with `react-scripts-ts` and ejected to configure webpack. I am using `react-async-component` to render pages async.

```
import { asyncComponent } from 'react-async-component';

const AsyncNotFoundPage = asyncComponent({
    resolve: () => import('./NotFoundPage').then(x => x.default)
});

export { AsyncNotFoundPage };
```

When I start the app, it works as it is expected. It splits the chunks of not found page. However, the following jest test case gives error;

```
describe('AsyncNotFoundPage Component', () => {

    it('should render async', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<AsyncNotFoundPage />);
        expect(wrapper.find(NotFoundPage)).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

It gives the following error;

`Unexpected token import`

I've tried to add all dynamic import plugins to babel config in package.json. It doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try require('moduleName'). I faced the same error and it resolved by using require('')

Comment: can you share babel config.. i am adding a general solution. hope it works

Comment: @hannadrehman babel config has only `react-app` preset by default

Comment: you can try below answer. i m sure its because of test env not having dynamic import plugin

Answer (score 1):

**Install babel-jest**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-jest
```

**Configure .babelrc for env**
Jest will change your `NODE_ENV` to "test" and Babel doesn't have any configuration for this env, we normally define Babel config for development and production env. When there is no babel transpilation, `import` keyword actually becomes undefined as it actually doesn't exist in JS context.

update your `.babelrc` to match following

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
        ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "dynamic-import-webpack"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if you are using some other plugins add them also in the test env

**Add jest.congfig.json to project root**

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

OR
**update your `package.Json` with jest config**

```
"jest": {
"transform": {
        "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
      }
}
```

if you are using `jest.config.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json --watch"
},
```

else

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "jest --watch"
    },
```

Comment: Is this going to run in typescript?

Comment: react-scripts-ts uses babel. you need to find where the babelrc file is kept

Comment: After eject, babel config resides in package.json

Comment: It works when I override `compilerOptions.module` as `commonjs` in tsconfig.test.jcon and disable `allowSyntheticImports` in tsconfig.json